# c# constraints ignored in extension with generic type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, generics

```
public interface ICardEntity { ... }

public class Card : ICardEntity { ... }

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static List<T> ToList<T>(this IQueryable<T> query) where T : ICardEntity
    { ... }
}

// DbContext
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
      public DbSet<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}

.....

var list = dbContext.Cards
     .ToList(); // -- OK, my extension is called
var list2 = dbContext.Cards
     .GroupBy(t => new { Type = t.Type})
     .ToList(); // -- Compile error. Why not System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList() is called?
```

I want my ToList to be invoked only for IQueryable< ICardEntity >, but not for IGrouping<< anonymous type: short H>, Card>. Why the constraint "where T : ICardEntity" don't work?

Error message:

> The type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<< anonymous type: short H>,
>   Nucleo.Tests.Models.Card>' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method 'MyExtensions.ToList(IQueryable)'. There
>   is no implicit reference conversion from
>   'System.Linq.IGrouping<,
>   Nucleo.Tests.Models.Card>' to 'ICardEntity'.

Comment: generic type constraints don't play a part in overload resolution.

Comment: btw, it is not necessary to create an anonymous type: `GroupBy(t => new { Type = t.Type })`. Why not `GroupBy(t => t.Type)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C#, **there is no overloading over generic constraints**. You can overload over parameter count and parameter types, but you cannot overload over return values, over generic constraints, etc. That's all.

During overload resolution, the compiler simply takes your ToList() because the name of method, and the number and type of parameter matches. It verifies generic constraints afterwards, but at that point it is already an error, not a overload-resolution-candidate-dropout. I don't know how to express it in a more readable way. I hope you get it.

after thought--

In case if you are used to C++ and its templates, then it's not C++ and there is no SFINAE which would simply make it work as you thought it would.

All 'overload resolution' and 'method matching/finding/etc' has to play along the rules of CLS/CLR, the whole platform for all languages like VB,C#,F3, etc. It is the CLS/CLR that defines how to lookup for methods, how to resolve overload candidates, and so on. And, sadly, overloading over generic type parameter constraints it is not included in the specs. IIRC adding it to specs would create several problems (IIRC, type&method resolution performance mostly) in the whole platform, so it was not added.. but that's what I remember. The important part is, it is not in the language and runtime platform specs.

Comment: Apparently it works differently in VB, since this is mentioned as part of (long) comments where [Eric Lippert explains this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/), so it's not necessarily a CLS/CLR thing.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: thanks for reminding me about VB's behavior. That's right. It works there in a different way. It seems that this specific thing is more about compiler design. - but - I believe that what I said about CLS/CLR is also true. If I remember correctly, if I call reflection (quite close to clr:) ) Type.GetMethod() and pass it a method name and Type[] with parameter specs, it will not overload over generic constraints. If you're sure I'm wrong about this, please tell me so, I'll remove that piece of text and I'll check it myself later in the evening.